# How do I fix Jenkins CI/CD Build Filepath Problem?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Build Shows successful but filepath shows
[Running on Java_SlaveNode1 in /home/devopsadmin/ /home/devopsadmin/ /home/devopsadmin/workspace/Pipeline_Project1]

should be
[home/devopsadmin/workspace/Pipeline_Project1]

Biuld shows successful but on entering[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaeTe.png)
[cd home/devopsadmin/workspace/Pipeline_Project1]
it says
[ls: cannot access '/home/devopsadmin/workspace/Pipeline_Project1': No such file or directory]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpi9P.png)

The filepath should not be /home/devopsadmin/ /home/devopsadmin/ /home/devopsadmin/workspace/Pipeline_Project1

It should be  home/devopsadmin/workspace/Pipeline_Project1